# Approximation of $\sqrt2$ using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the differential equation
>   $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac1{2x}.$$
>   This is a separable O.D.E. so we know how to find all of its solutions: they are of the form $$x(t)=\sqrt{t+C}$$
>   where $C$ is a constant. Imposing the initial condition $x(1)=1$ fixes $C=0$. Then we have $x(2)=\sqrt2$.
>
> Using [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) with $h=1/2$ find an approximation to $\sqrt2$. Provide a numeric answer rounded to two decimal places.

[image]
Can't seem to be getting anywhere. Can someone please give me hint/solution of the question in the link above?

Comment: Have you written down Euler's Method for the solution of a first order DE? That will give you a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We exploit the fact that $x(t)=\sqrt t$ satisfies the given differential equation with initial condition $x(1)=1$. Using [Euler's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), we then get:

$$x\left(\frac32\right)\approx x(1)+\frac12\cdot x'(1)=1+\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot1}=\frac54$$
$$x(2)\approx x\left(\frac32\right)+\frac12\cdot x'\left(\frac32\right)\approx \frac54 + \frac12\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot\frac54}=\frac{29}{20}=1.45$$

Hence $\sqrt2=x(2)\approx1.45$

Comment: @B.Goddard Any reason to bring that up in such a rude fashion nearly six years later? If this person cheated on their homework or a test or whatever, that's their own problem and their own fault. Do you know anything about them to suggest that their life was ruined by asking this question? Even if so, why the heck are you rubbing salt in the wound? At any rate, this is a Q&A site; A'ers can't possibly be expected to know if Q'ers aren't allowed to ask their Q. I really wish you wouldn't have suggested I'm somehow responsible for ruining someone's life by answering a question in good faith.

Comment: @sbares  Often people get downvoted for answering questions like this, which show no effort.  You're not following MSE guidelines, so that makes you the rude one.