# Need a hint using Runge-Kutta to solve this

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

> Recall the fourth order Runge-Kutta method:
>   $$x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac16(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4)$$
>   Apply it, with $h = 1$ to the initial value problem in the previous question to obtain a better approximation to $\sqrt2$. Provide a numerical answer rounded to five decimal places.

I need a hint solving this equation. Please help!

Comment: What, exactly, is "the previous question"? And what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I do not understand, where to insert h. i tried 
k4 = hf(xn + k3, tn + h)

Comment: The first problem is this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599366/i-need-a-hint-solving-this-one-using-eulers-method/1599386#1599386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation in question is
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{2x}, \quad x(1) = 1
$$
which has general solution $x(t) = \sqrt{t+C}$, and with the given initial value, we get the specific solution $x(t) = \sqrt t$. That means that starting at $t_0 = 1$, and using some numerical method with $h = 1$, we should get to an approximation of $\sqrt2$ in one step. We are told to use Runge-Kutta of fourth order, and that is what we're going to do.

Gathering what we're given, both from the problem itself and the definition of fourth-order Runge-Kutta, we have
$$
f(t, x) = \frac 1{2x}\\
x_0 = 1\\
t_0 = 0\\
x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac16(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4)\\
k_1 = f(t_n, x_n)\\
k_2 = f(t_n + \frac12, x_n + \frac{k_1}{2})\\
k_3 = f(t_n + \frac12, x_n + \frac{k_2}{2})\\
k_4 = f(t_n + 1, x_n + k_3)
$$
(Note that there are supposed to be quite a lot of $h$ strewn in here and there as well. Since we're told that $h = 1$, I've skipped those.)

The solution to our problem is $x_1$. So we just start calculating:
$$
k_1 = f(t_0, x_0) = \frac{1}{2x_0} = \frac12\\
k_2 = f(t_0 + \frac12, x_0 + \frac{k_1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2(x_0 + k_1/2)} = \frac{1}{2(1 + 1/4)} = \frac25\\
k_3 = f(t_0 + \frac12, x_0 + \frac{k_2}{2}) = \frac1{2(x_0 + k_2/2)} = \frac{1}{2(1 + 1/5)} = \frac{5}{12}\\
k_4 = f(t_0 + 1, x_0 + k_3) = \frac{1}{2(x_0 + k_3)} = \frac{1}{2(1 + \frac{5}{12})} = \frac{6}{17}
$$
and with this we can enter everything into the final expression:
$$
x_1 = x_0 + \frac16(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4)\\
= 1 + \frac16\left(\frac12 + \frac45 + \frac56 + \frac6{17}\right)\\
= \frac{1082}{765} \approx 1.414379084967320261437
$$

Comment: You are such a boss O.O